# Java fx event handler

Tags: javafx, eventhandler

Why my code is not running? How am I going to display an image on the interface when clicked "add image"?

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class GUIProject extends Application{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void start (Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Pane bPane = new Pane();

        Button btOK = new Button("OK");
        OKAction OKact = new OKAction();
        btOK.setOnAction(OKact);

        Button addImage = new Button("Add Image");
        isAdd addimage = new isAdd();
        addImage.setOnAction(addimage);

        //bPane.getChildren().add(btOK);
        bPane.getChildren().add(addImage);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Pane extends StackPane {

   public void addImage() throws Exception
    {
        Image logo = new Image(new FileInputStream("logo.jpg"));
            ImageView logoView = new ImageView(logo);
            this.getChildren().add(logoView);
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


class isAdd implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
    {
        try {
            Pane.displayImage();
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");;
        }

    }

}
```

It keep showing static method cannot with non-static method, how can I solve that?
Is there any website can learn javafx event handler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+non-static+method+cannot+be+called+from+a+static+context

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them